# Javascript files not loading when hosting a website on digital ocean

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs, digital-ocean

I've built a web app with an express backend and using the ejs view engine.

When I run it on my computer it works fine but I'm trying to host in on digitalocean. I cloned it to the droplet(Ubuntu 22.10 x64) and served it on port 80. When I visited it in the browser at 46.101.145.210:80, I got these errors.

```
GET https://46.101.145.210/javascripts/cookieHandler.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED               
GET https://46.101.145.210/javascripts/domain.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Here's my file structure,

[image]

Here's the code in index.js.

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path")
const assert = require("assert");

const PORT = 80

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.static('public'));

app.set("view engine", "ejs")

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log("Server running on port " + PORT.toString());
});

const domains = ... // Not important

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.render("index")
    //res.redirect("/domain")
})

app.get("/domain", (req, res) => {
    res.render("domain", {domains: domains})
})
```

I've tinkered with the firewall config and the express.static to see if it would make a difference. I couldn't figure anything out though.

Update: I've checked the requests out a bit. They are https requests. When I use postman and change the request to be http it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by adding a valid ssl certificate.

Comment: Excellent, if you solved this, please close the question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looking your file structure and the code, I can say, you must define the full path of the `public` directory using

```js
express.static(__dirname+'/public')
```

Or can be like

```js
const path = require('path');

// .... your code ...

app.use(express.static( path.join(__dirname, 'public') ));
```

with this you are forcing to define where the public directory is on the ubuntu, and validate you are accessing your files

Hope you can solve with this

Update: checking carefully, I can see that your are trying to request using https, but your code is working on port 80 (http), so you said, on postman worked without https because of the port. If you want to have working your code with port 443 (https), you must have a certificate (with domain but not required), then try with `https://46.101.145.210/javascripts/cookieHandler.js` otherwhise try `http://46.101.145.210/javascripts/cookieHandler.js`.

Comment: I've tried that but it doesn't change anything.